# How to fix django IntegrityError?

Tags: python, django, web

I meet this error when I try to submit form data from front to my web server.I am confused why this happened.

> **IntegrityError at /qa/propose-answer/7/**
>   **(1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null")**
>   Request Method:   POST 
>   Request URL:  http://192.168.109.146:8000/qa/propose-answer/7/ 
>   Django Version:   2.1.7 
>   Exception Value:  (1048, "Column 'created_at' cannot be null") 
>   ExceptionLocation:/home/anaconda3/envs/zhuri02/lib/python3.7/sitepackages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute, line 76
>   Python Executable:    /home/anaconda3/envs/zhuri02/bin/python
>   Python Version:   3.7.4

My models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    uuid_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='a_author', verbose_name='回答者')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='回答的问题')
    content = MarkdownxField(verbose_name='内容')
    is_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='回答是否被接受')
    votes = GenericRelation(Vote, verbose_name='投票情况')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='创建时间')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='更新时间')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-is_answer', '-created_at')
        verbose_name = '回答'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

My views.py

```
class CreateAnswerView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['content', ]
    template_name = 'qa/answer_form.html'
    message = '您的回答已提交'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.question_id = self.kwargs['question_id']
        return super(CreateAnswerView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        reverse_lazy('qa:question_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['question_id']})
```

My template

```
    <form action="{% url 'qa:propose_answer' view.kwargs.question_id %}" id="answerForm" method="post" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="answer" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">回答</button>
            <a class="btn btn-light" style="float:right" href="{% url 'qa:all_q' %}">取消</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: did you run the migrations before testing the code? Also can you share the full error stacktrace please?

Comment: I have forget the “return” in get_success_url method